# How to reply to a particular user's most recent tweet using Tweepy?

Tags: python, twitter, bots, tweepy

I found this code

```
toReply = "xxx" 
api = tweepy.API(auth)



tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name = toReply, count=1)

for tweet in tweets:
api.update_status("@" + toReply + " my reply", in_reply_to_status_id = tweet.id)
```

But it's not what I'm looking for. It just replies to the latest tweet. I want the bot to reply every time xxx tweets. What should I change in my code?

Answer (score 2):

```
while True:
  for tweet in api.user_timeline(...):
```